# Accessing array within an array using a string as the key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Im currently trying to build a validation class in PHP.
What im trying to do is match the array of validations required with the `$_POST` array.
My validation array gives the following values which are field names

```
$validation[0] = “order[0][company]”
$validation[1] = “order[1][company]”
$validation[2] = “order[2][company]”
```

And so on.
The `$_POST` array looks like this

```
Array ( [order] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [company] => [link] => [username] => [password] => [comments] => ) [1] => Array ( [company] => [link] => [username] => [password] => [comments] => )
```

How do I access the value from the post array using the field names given above?
I tried `$_POST[$validation[0]]` but it doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

$_POST[$validation[0]], with a pair of brackets instead of parentheses, as you'd access any other array.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my question, thats what i'm doing.